# Gitlab CI not recognizing variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

I'm currently facing an issue with Gitlab CI, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. The problem revolves around variables not being recognized in the URL when using Gitlab CI.

I have a scenario where, if I hardcode the complete URL, everything works as expected. However, when I try to use a variable like baseUrl coming from CYPRESS_BASE_URL, Gitlab CI doesn't seem to pick it up. Of course happens the same with CYPRESS_USERNAME, CYPRESS_PASSWORD

**Here's a snippet of my test in cypress**

```
const baseUrl = Cypress.env("CYPRESS_BASE_URL");
const user = Cypress.env("CYPRESS_USER");
const password = Cypress.env("CYPRESS_PASSWORD");

describe('Login and Sort', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit(baseUrl);
    cy.login(user, password);
  });
```

**The .gitlab-ci.yml file in the Pipeline Editor**

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
  CYPRESS_BASE_URL: "$CYPRESS_BASE_URL"
  CYPRESS_ENDPOINT: "$CYPRESS_ENDPOINT"
  CYPRESS_USER: "$CYPRESS_USER"
  CYPRESS_PASSWORD: "$CYPRESS_PASSWORD"

test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  stage: test

  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run chrome
```

**Then according to documentation I tried this just to see if the baseUrl could pass through but no:**

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
  CYPRESS_BASE_URL: "CYPRESS_BASE_URL"
  CYPRESS_ENDPOINT: "CYPRESS_ENDPOINT"
  CYPRESS_USER: "CYPRESS_USER"
  CYPRESS_PASSWORD: "CYPRESS_PASSWORD"

test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  stage: test

  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run chrome
    - echo "The URL is '$CYPRESS_BASE_URL'"
```

**the variables in CI/CD Settings**

[image]

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you access variables in Cypress, they're not the same as the OS-level environment variables. Cypress automatically removes the leading `CYPRESS_` from the variable name in the case of variables added using the `CYPRESS_` prefix convention.

Hence, if your OS environment variable is set as `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`, you should use `Cypress.env('BASE_URL')` to access it, not `Cypress.env('CYPRESS_BASE_URL')`.

```js
const baseUrl = Cypress.env("BASE_URL");
const user = Cypress.env("USER");
const password = Cypress.env("PASSWORD");
```

See the [`Cypress.env`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env) and [Cypress Environment Variables documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that to CY_BASE_URL. I did that in all my files (CY_USER, CY_PASSWORD..., etc)  but still can't grab any of these variables.

Comment: @SantiR I don't think that will work. You must use `CYPRESS_`, not `CY_` as the environment variable prefix.  Please check the linked documentation more closely.

Comment: sorry I'm confused. Locally it runs ok with whenever name I add, since cypress.env.js matches with config and the test files. So you are saying to remove CYPRESS_BASE_URL and leave const baseUrl = Cypress.env("BASE_URL") as you just mentioned in the test file, config, command.js etc. BUT in Gilab Ci when adding the variable under the CI configuration tab to add CYPRESS_BASE_URL and the corresonding URL value. Sorry Im very new to this cloud stuff

Comment: Seems that with that change removing CYPRESS_  in the code but leaving it in the CI Confirguration of Gitlab works with the ENDPOINT file , not the BASE_URL. But it's progress. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

@sytech pointed me in the direction to find one of the issues. Thank you very much!

Also got some other help, I erased the block code with all the variables. That is no needed

[image]

and also I was calling again cy.visit in other files, it was already under command.js . this is how all the files were fixed

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user, password) => {
      cy.visit('/');
      cy.get('[data-test="username"]').type(user);
      cy.get('[data-test="password"]').type(password);
      cy.get('[data-test="login-button"]').click(); 
})
```

**API spec**

```
const endPoint = Cypress.env("ENDPOINT");  *<<--- as @cytech mentioned removing the CYPRESS_ before ENDPOINT*

describe("GET Public API's - Entries", () => {
    it("Status 200", () => {
        cy.request("GET", endPoint).should((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
        expect(response.body).to.have.property('entries');
        });
    });


    it('Entries with Authentication & Authorization', () => {
        cy.request(endPoint)  
        .its('body.entries').then((entries)=>{
            const authEntries = entries.filter((item) => {
                return item.Category === 'Authentication & Authorization';
                });
                cy.log(`${authEntries.length} Entries with Category "Authentication & Authorization": `);
                cy.log(JSON.stringify(authEntries, null, 2));
        })
    });
});
```

**login spec**

```
const user = Cypress.env("USER");
const password = Cypress.env("PASSWORD");

*// just using the user password variables since login under commands.js is already making a cy.visit()*

describe('Login and Sort', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login(user, password);
  });
```